# how to calculate no of tokens in a text file in nlp

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

```
from urllib import request
from redditscore.tokenizer import CrazyTokenizer
tokenizer = CrazyTokenizer()
url = "http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~diana/csi5386/A1_2020/microblog2011.txt"
with open('your_file.txt', 'a',encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as f:
    for line in request.urlopen(url):
        tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(line.decode('utf-8'))
        print(tokens)
        for item in tokens:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

In the above I've tokenized a url and written that output to a text file. How calculate the number of tokens in the file ?

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers hey can you help me on this?

Comment: Could you not just make a total variable (`total = 0`)?  Then each iteration of the `for` loop, just do `total += len(tokens)`

Comment: @Jason make this this an answer!